# Dynamically add a groupid and find the distinct count sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, row

```
Source Data:

TID Pid OpID
1   41  1
1   41  2
1   44  1
1   69  1
1   248 1
1   255 1
1   255 2
4   41  1
4   41  2
4   44  1
4   69  1
4   248 1
4   255 1
4   255 2
6   41  1
6   44  1
6   69  1
6   248 1
6   255 1
6   255 2
15  41  1
15  248 1
15  255 1
15  255 2
16  41  1
16  248 1
16  255 1
16  255 2

output:

Pid OpID    Unique TId_count
41  1   2
41  2   2
44  1   2
69  1   2
248 1   2
255 1   2
255 2   2
41  1   1
44  1   1
69  1   1
248 1   1
255 1   1
255 2   1
41  1   2
248 1   2
255 1   2
255 2   2
```

Rules:

1) At first i need to find what are the available PID and OperationID for each TID
2) later consider PID and OPID as a set(group) and find the possible combination of TID and display distinct TID count
Example:

i) for the `PID {41,41,44,69,248,255,255}` and `OperationId {1,2,1,1,1,1,2}` is falling in two tester `{1,4}` so I need the output `TID` count is 2.

ii) for the `PID {41,44,69,248,255,255}` and `OperationId {1,1,1,1,1,2}` is falling in single tester `{6}` so i need the output `TID` count is `1`.

iii) Finally, for the `PID {41,248,255,255}` and `OperationId {1,1,1,2}` is falling in two tester `{15,16}` so i need the output `TID` count is `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine any use for this ... but check out this anyway:

```
select pid, opid, count(*) from
(select tid, pid, opid,
    (SELECT ',' + cast(x.pid as nvarchar(10))
                        FROM #temp x
                        WHERE x.tid = t.tid
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) as PidGroup,
    (SELECT ',' + cast(x.OpId as nvarchar(10))
                        FROM #temp x
                        WHERE x.tid = t.tid
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) as OpIdGroup
    from #temp t) innerselect
group by pid, opid, PidGroup, opidgroup
```

it produces the output you want ... just replace #temp with your tablename.

Comment: Thanks,i got the tester count. But for the users the group must be in order as i showed in my output.

Comment: the Order Should not be changed. It is not random.
<pre>
Pid OpID    Unique TId_count
41  1   2
41  2   2
44  1   2
69  1   2
248 1   2
255 1   2
255 2   2
</pre>

Comment: select pid, opid, count(*)
 from
 (select tid, pid, opid,
   (SELECT ',' + cast(x.pid as nvarchar(10))
        FROM #temp x
        WHERE x.tid = t.tid
         FOR XML PATH ('')) as PidGroup,
   (SELECT ',' + cast(x.OpId as nvarchar(10))
        FROM #temp x
        WHERE x.tid = t.tid
         FOR XML PATH ('')) as OpIdGroup,
   row_number() over(order by tid, pid, opid) as num
  from #temp t) innerselect
 group by pid, opid, PidGroup, opidgroup
 order by min(innerselect.num)

Comment: Thanks a lot It help me.. perfect matching with my result